# Cleanest way to parse this pattern of strings?

Tags: c#, .net, regex, string, parsing

I have music file names like:

```
Gorillaz (2001)
Gorillaz (7th State Mix) (2002)
Gorillaz (2001) (Featuring Travis)
Gorillaz (1Mix) (2003)
Gorillaz (1000) (2001)
```

How do I parse the year in the cleanest, easiest way?

Right now I am parsing them by finding each `'('` and then making sure the character count between the `()`s are 4 and first char is 1 or 2 and they can be parsed, using `TryParse`?

Can I parse these kinds of strings using a single Regex?

---

#### Edit:

The year can be max 50-60 years old, so not older than 1950.

Comment: Do you absolutely have to parse the file names like that? Are there data structures you can use to store this information?

Comment: Here are some more test cases for you:

Prince Remix (1999) (1999)
2001 Soundtrack (2001) (1974)

Comment: @Brian, yes I use a data structure for it, which I then need to pass the year.

Comment: Your first problem is listening to the Gorillaz.  `</obligatory>`

Answer (score 8):

I think this does what you're after:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string[] samples = new[] { "Gorillaz (2001)",
                "Gorillaz (7th State Mix) (2002)",
                "Gorillaz (2001) (Featuring Travis)",
                "Two matches: (2002) (1950)",
                "Gorillaz (1Mix) (1952)",
                "Gorillaz (1Mix) (2003)",
                "Gorillaz (1000) (2001)" };

        foreach (string name in samples)
        {
            ShowMatches(name);
        }
    }

    static readonly Regex YearRegex = new Regex(@"\((19[5-9]\d|200\d)\)");

    static void ShowMatches(string name)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Matches for: {0}", name);
        foreach (Match match in YearRegex.Matches(name))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(match.Value);
        }
    }
}
```

That will work as far as 2009. To make it work beyond that, use @"((19[5-9]\d|20[01]\d))" etc.

Note that that still prints out the brackets - you *could* get rid of them with a group construct, but personally I'd just use `Substring` :)

Comment: Might want to make that 2\d{3} -- then you won't need to rewrite it for the next thousand years.

Comment: No, it's deliberately like that - so that it won't miscategorize 2500 (which clearly *isn't* a year).

Comment: (Admittedly when you make it 20[01]\d it'll still assume that 2019 is a year when it's only 2010, but hey...)

Comment: Thanks Jon, do you know what do I need to cover say a 149 years? SO from 1950 to 2099? Can I come up with a single regex for that?

Comment: I just tried @"((19[5-9]\d|20[01]\d))", but that didn't match 2055. I thought it's better to find a regex that's good for 149 years.

Comment: I used @"\\((19[5-9]\d|20[0-9]\d)\\)", it worked. Is this an ok regex to use?

Comment: Well you could use that, or just \d\d at the end to match two digits (or indeed \d{2}).

Comment: Btw I tried replacing the end like you said, but I mess it up. Is it how it should be? @"\\((19[5-9]\d|20[0-9]\d{2}))"? When I do that, it doesn't find any match.

Answer (score 2):

This regex will match your pattern:

```
@"\(([12]\d{3})\)"
```

You can then extract Group 1 to get the year.  You can then use `Convert.ToInt32` to get the year as an `int`, and check it is greater than 1950 (it's probably better to do this as a numeric comparison rather than overcomplicating the regex).

Answer (score 1):

you should be able to match this using regex.
Here is a pattern you might try to use:

```
\([12][0-9]{3}\)
```

Don't forget to enable greedy. This will match the (1000) on the last line, as well. Is this wanted, too?

**Edit:**

```
 \((19|20)[0-9]{2}\)
```

will do the job if you don't want the (1000) as a match

regards

Comment: I think that it's not supposed to match the `(1000)` in the last line since the year won't be any earlier than 1950.

Comment: it does not match 1000, right. well... 1000 _is_ actually earlier than 1950 ;) but yes, that's not the reason it doesn't get matched.
jon's pattern in his code looks better anyway :P

Answer (score 1):

Considering you have things that look like years but aren't e.g. (1000) I would look for 19**, 20**, and maybe 21** if you think your program is going to be around for a while :)

```
/\(19\d\d|20\d\d|21\d\d\)/
```

For your inputs this gives:

```
2001
2002
2001
2003
2001
2001
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks tricky unless we know more about what some of those parenthese are for:  if you could have a "`(1000)`" that's not really a year, you could probably have a "`(2000)`" that's not really a year also.  I'm talking about the last line in your sample:

> Gorillaz (1000) (2001)

If that's valid, why not something like this? :

> Gorillaz (2000) (2001)

Where the `(2000)` in the latter example fills the same conceptual role as the `(1000)` from the former (it's not a year).  How will your regex know which is the year?  If you know this won't happen, *how* do you now it won't happen?

Comment: He says the music is not older than 60 years.

Comment: Thanks Joel. What do you mean when you said 2000 isn't a year?

Comment: I see. The year will only start from 1950. If there are 2 valid years which might, then only the first one will be used. I will document this so if the user has files like these, then it's his responsibility to make sure they only have 1 year.

Comment: I don't think you quite have it yet.  I'm talking about a separate attribute that's not a year at all, but still happens on occasion to be 4 a digit number between 1950 and 2050.

Comment: I see. But you mean a value like that but also inside parenthesis? Isn't that unlikely? :)

Comment: From your sample, it looks almost inevitable.

Comment: Yeah I see what you mean. But I think that's still not very likely. You are right I had values like that. It's just that sometimes you come across half number half text in parenthesis, sometimes all numbers but not exactly 4 characters. If 4 characters then, most likely not a valid year. If it's a valid year, mostly it's outside the parenthesis like Overkill 2000 or something, but if it's inside the parenthesis, there is definitely a user problem with file names. A music file shouldn't have 2 different years both inside parenthesis and both valid. Makes sense?

Comment: Also I mentioned Gorillaz (1000) (2001), just to eliminate cases with very close but invalid years. If more than 1 valid years, then I will just choose the 1st one.